# Spliting / Slicing Text File with Python

Tags: python

Im learning python, I´ve been trying to split this txt file into multiple files grouped by a sliced string at the beginning of each line.

currently i have two issues:

1 - The string can have 5 or 6 chars is marked by a space at the end.(as in WSON33 and JHSF3 etc...)

Here is an exemple of the file i would like to split ( first line is a header):

```
H24/06/202000003TORDISTD 
BWSON33      0803805000000000016400000003250C000002980002415324C1 0000000000000000
BJHSF3       0804608800000000003500000000715V000020280000031810C1 0000000000000000
```

2- I´ve come with a lot of code, but i´m not able to put everything together so this can work:

This code here i adappeted from another post and it kind of works breaking into multiple files, but it requires a sorting of the lines before i start writing files, i aslo need to copy the header in each file and not isolete it one file.

```
with open('tordist.txt', 'r') as fin:

# group each line in input file by first part of split
for i, (k, g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(fin, lambda l: l.split()[0]),1):
    # create file to write to suffixed with group number - start = 1
    with open('{0} tordist.txt'.format(i), 'w') as fout:
        
        # for each line in group write it to file
        for line in g:
            fout.write(line.strip() + '\n')
```

Comment: What do you mean "grouped by a sliced string at the beginning of each line"?

Comment: Ur question is not clear. Please specify input and output format

Comment: use split func to split the string. "YourString".split(" "),this will split ur string on thr basis of whitespace

Comment: Can you clarify your question(s)? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can gather, you have a text file with many lines, where every line begins with a short string of 5 or six characters.  It sounds like you want all the lines that begin with the same string to go into the same file, so that after the code is run you have as many new files as there are unique starting strings.  Is that accurate?

Like you, I'm fairly new to python, and so I'm sure there are more compact ways to do this.  The code below loops through the file a number of times, and makes new files in the same folder as the file where your text and python files are.

```
# code which separates lines in a file by an identifier,
#and makes new files for each identifier group

filename = input('type filename')
if len(filename) < 1:
  filename = "mk_newfiles.txt"
filehandle = open(filename)

#This chunck loops through the file, looking at the beginning of each line,
#and adding it to a list of identifiers if it is not on the list already.
Unique = list()
for line in filehandle:
#like Lalit said, split is a simple way to seperate a longer string
  line = line.split()
  if line[0] not in Unique:
      Unique.append(line[0])

#For each item in the list of identifiers, this code goes through
#the file, and if a line starts with that identifier then it is
#added to a new file.
for item in Unique:
    #this 'if' skips the header, which has a '/' in it
    if '/' not in item:
        # the .seek(0) 'rewinds' the iteration variable, which is apperently needed
        #needed if looping through files multiple times
        filehandle.seek(0)

        #makes new file
        newfile = open(str(item) + ".txt","w+")

        #inserts header, and goes to next line
        newfile.write(Unique[0])
        newfile.write('\n')

        #goes through old file, and adds relevant lines to new file
        for line in filehandle:
            split_line = line.split()
            if item == split_line[0]:
                newfile.write(line)

print(Unique)
```

Comment: You understood correctly! thanks for taking the time to share your code with me. I will let you know what i found later on.